# sending a message using openTok

Tags: swift, swift3, opentok

I am trying to create a chat app using openTok(Swift 3) but having a issue to send messages to other users in the session. I do receive the connection of other users but unable to send the message. Instead of sending a message ,I, myself receives it.I tried to send it to a single person as follow:

```
func sendMessage() {
    session = OTSession(apiKey: ApiKey, sessionId: SessionID, delegate: self)
    session?.signal(withType: "Chat", string: "Hi", connection: (session?.connection)!, retryAfterReconnect: true, error: nil)
}
```

when i tried to send to all users in the session then it says 'Ambiguous reference to member session': please see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJJBD.png)

also when i check function source (clicked function holding down command key) then it goes to NSLock.h in Foundation Framework

now i don't know where to go or what to do!

Comment: 2 things: 
1) the session needs to be connected in order for a signal to be accepted. 
2) In the screenshot, the session variable is out of scope. This probably should be an instance variable on the class implementing the method.

Comment: OpenTok also has text chat accelerator pack you can use: https://github.com/opentok/textchat-acc-pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, @wobbals is correct. First of all, you have to call `open func connect(withToken token: String!, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<OTError?>!)` and receive `public func sessionDidConnect(_ session: OTSession!)` afterwards in order to enable the `session` object to send signals. Please do remember to record the error so you will have some ideas what happen if failure.

From the documentation, the connected session will broadcast to every connection, including yourself, if you pass `nil` to the connection parameter. I believe this line `session?.signal(withType: "Chat", string: "Hi", connection: (session?.connection)!, retryAfterReconnect: true, error: nil)` will crash your application because of unwrapping a `nil` object due to the `nil` value of `session?.connection` if session is not connected.

Just a side note, it's actually confused here if you post code and also an image. We don't know which is your actual problem is. But, they both have obvious issues.